# How do I UPDATE an SQL table with a sheet in excel

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, import

I have some SQL skill but I have a problem:
I currently get a monthly excel sheet via email containing 1 sheet of information. I need to be able to completely update and replace a table in SQL server 2008 (express) with this information.

I have tried to create a proceedure to drop the table and recreate it using something like this

```
Drop Table Utah

Create table Utah


Insert into dbo.[Utah] 
Select *    FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
        'Excel 8.0;Database=c:< .sxl file here>;HDR=YES', 
    'SELECT * FROM [Utah]')
```

But im not having any luck when I try to make a proceedure for this.

Each step seems to work on its own but to streamline this and make it easy for others to do - Can you help me please?

Comment: If you want to create the table using the `INSERT INTO ....` - you should make sure it doesn't exist first (that's the `DROP TABLE`) - but you should **NOT** already try to create that table again yourself; `INSERT INTO` will do that for you.

Comment: marc_s -- how INSERT INTO will create the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to create SSIS job.

There you can automate the process to handle excel files and refresh the sql tables and all.Its going to be very smooth and handy.

In case of SQL Express tyr to run this code as Sproc

```
IF EXISTS(select * from sysobjects where name='Utah' and type='U')
DROP TABLE Utah
GO

Create table Utah(col1 int,col2 int)
Go

Insert into dbo.[Utah] 
Select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
        'Excel 8.0;Database=c:< .sxl file here>;HDR=YES', 
    'SELECT * FROM [Utah]')

Go
```

Comment: Is SSIS available on server 2008 express? When I look at the install I have selected all of the items available in the R2 package.

Comment: Thank you AnandPhadke this seems to work. Is it possible to put this type of sql statement into a Stored procedure? I've tried but on execution it doesn't seem to work the same.

Comment: remove first 2 Go statements from the above code.Just keep the last go and put that in sproc